# Disable double opt-in in Mailchimp api 3.0 using PHP

Tags: php, mailchimp

I read multiple threads here and on several other sites. They all said that in able to disable double opt-in I need to register the user as "subscribed". That didn't work.
Here is my code:

```
 $data = [
 'email'     => $_GET['email'],
 'status'    => 'subscribed'
 ];
 syncMailchimp($data);
static function syncMailchimp($data) {
        $apiKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXX-us3';
        $listId = 'XXXXXXXXXX';

        $memberId = md5(strtolower($data['email']));
        $dataCenter = substr($apiKey,strpos($apiKey,'-')+1);
        $url = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $listId . '/members/' . $memberId;

        $json = json_encode([
                'email_address' => $data['email'],
                'status'        => $data['status'], // "subscribed","unsubscribed","cleaned","pending"
        ]);

        $ch = curl_init($url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $apiKey);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $httpCode;


}
```

When I try and disable the double opt-in from within the account, it's greyed out and won't let me uncheck it:
[image]

If you have any idea, I'd love to hear it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like that MailChimp Account might be in a compliance state. Sometimes this can require that lists be double opt-in mode. I would log into that account and look for any notifications in the top top-right-hand corner that would indicate that this is the case.

Hope this helps out!

Comment: That's actually pretty correct. I realized I added a whole lot of emails from a previous list there and they bounced which screwed up the account. I ended up opening a new account and everything worked just fine. Thanks